# Redux toolkit createApi search by api query data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux-toolkit RTK, and I'm loving it. But I have a problem.

Basically, I'm calling a URL that returns a data, then I want to render various sub elements. Let me explain better.

My main screen has a parameter `pathname` that I use to call `const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useGetArticleQuery(route.params?.pathname);`

But then I would like to use a component like this `<News id={data.id} />`

The question is: How can I do something like a selector to look up article query result by id?

Thank you very much!